# Edit vertices of intersections from multiple lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, intersection, line, vertices

I would like to edit the vertex where two lines intersect, but doing so makes me manually move each vertex of each line. I tried to merge the lines but it did not work.

Is there an easier way to move the point of intersection without having to move vertices from both lines independently?

Comment: Create a geometric network - this will inherently create junctions at the intersection of line and point.

Comment: Create end points. Try snap tool; repeat from results window.  Alternativly install arcview 3. Not a joke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way within ArcGIS is to work with a [topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Selecting_topology_edges/01mm00000007000000/).

- Load your feature class into ArcMap.
- Open the topology toolbar.
- Click "Select topology" and select your feature class.
- Now click on the vertex that's shared by multiple lines to move it.

Comment: thank you. that really helped. though i have to use "Feature to Line" first before using topolgy.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool below highlighted in image. *"Select and move a node dhared between several polyline"*.

[image]